# How to setup my button component to open a window

Tags: qt, click, qml, qtquick2

Here is the code of the window I wanna be opened in file `PopUpFreeCoins.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
Item {
    property int t
    property int c
    ListModel{
        id:ff
        ListElement {
            name: "ByFollow"
            s: "Images/follow.png"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "ByLike"
            s: "Images/care.png"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "ByComment"
            s: "Images/chat.png"
        }
    }
    ListView{
        width:t-t/10
        height: c/5
        layoutDirection:Qt.LeftToRight
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        model: ff
        spacing:50
        delegate: Button{
            contentItem:  Image{
            source: s
        }}
    }
}
```

property `t` is set equal to window `width` in main file and property `c` is set to window `height`. This is code of my `Button.qml`:

```
Button{//Below Right
        width:profilePicture.width/2
        height:profilePicture.width/2
        x:profilePicture.x+profilePicture.width
        y:profilePicture.y+profilePicture.height
        contentItem: Image {
            source: "Images/freecoins.png"
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
        onClicked: PopUp{height:100;width:300;PopUpFreeCoins{t:a;c:b;}}
    }
```

property `a` is window width and `b` is window height.
this line             `onClicked: PopUp{height:100;width:300;PopUpFreeCoins{t:a;c:b;}}` has an error I don't know how to handle!
Here is the error:

> Cannot assign object type PopUpFreeCoins_QMLTYPE_0 with no default
>   method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the Object somehow. You have multiple ways for dynamically create Objects. One way is to use `Component.createObject(parent)` which requires you to have a `Component` instantiated in your file.
Here you can also pass a Object (`{property0 : value, property1:value ... }`) as second argument, to set the properties of the `Component` to be instantiated. You should not set the parent to `null` as it might happen, that the JS-garbage collector is too aggressive once again.

Alternatively you can use the `Loader` to load it from either a `source` (QML-file) or `sourceComponent`. Here you won't have problems with the garbage collector.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 1024
    height: 800

    visible: true

    Button {
        text: 'create'
        onClicked: test.createObject(this)
    }

    Button {
        x: 200
        text: 'load'
        onClicked: loader.active = !loader.active
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
        source: 'TestObj.qml'
        active: false
    }

    Component {
        id: test
        TestObj {}
    }
}
```

`TestObj.qml` includes the `Window` to be opened.

Alternatively you can have the `Window` created from the beginning, and just change the `visible` to `true` or `false`.